# breakatwhitespace undefined

Tags: errors, listings, packages

I try to use several latex template (Metropolis beamer theme, etc.) but I got the following error:

```
! Package keyval Error: breakatwhitespace undefined.
```

I think this error not from the package but from my latex. I've installed latex in my Ubuntu 16.04 using `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

How to solve this error? Hope somebody here can help.

**UPDATE**

I got this error several times, it always involve theme / template. The newest happen when I try to compile [Metropolis Beamer Theme](https://github.com/matze/mtheme). At this time, I even didn't write any code, I just follow the installation tutorial, and get error after trying to install using `make install`. Usually I just try to find in the templates/theme where is the `breakatwhitspace` and delete it.

`breakatwhitespace` I think included when using package `listings` and the theme/template author use `lstset` :

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    ...
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    ...
}
```

the code below give the error (I copy paste the `\usepackage{listings}` and `\lstset` from Metropolis beamer template):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{mLightBrown}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{mLightGreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mLightGreen},
    backgroundcolor=\color{mBackground},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
    stepnumber=2,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    frame=none,
    framerule=1pt,
    tabsize=2,
    rulesep=5em,
    captionpos=b,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    framexleftmargin=0em,
    framexrightmargin=0em,
    xleftmargin=0em,
    xrightmargin=0em,
    aboveskip=1em,
    belowskip=1em,
    morekeywords={usetheme,institute,maketitle,@metropolis@titleformat,%
                  plain,setbeamercolor,metroset,setsansfont,setmonofont},
  }

\begin{document}
    \frame{\titlepage}  
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE 2**

The first few lines logs show my system version:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled
...
```

Comment: but the code above , give me error here, `breakatwhitespace undefined`

Comment: Oh, thank you I'll try to update my version, May be you can put your solution as answer in case it will solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this solution from this thread (even have different problem indication):

[How to upgrade the package "listings" on Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335092/how-to-upgrade-the-package-listings-on-ubuntu)

and the problem is in fpc version. Solution is uninstall `fp-utils-3.0.0`:

```
sudo apt-get remove fp-utils-3.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, your used TeX distribution `Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)` is a little bit old.

With my current MiKTeX `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400 64-bit)` I can compile your given code without errors!

I suggest you to update your system.

Are you **short before** a deadline? Then better do the update **after** the deadline, because it could be that you get more errors after the update (depends on your used code) ...

Comment: I've update it to `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)` but it still give an error :(